# Insert and Delete cell in tableview , put textfield in cell and then textfield data put in json raw parameter in swift

Tags: ios, swift

[description image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UvMr.png)

[description image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVi3w.png)

My goal is to repeat the view at the bottom page using the "Add More" button

At the end of the data insertion, when the user presses the SUBMIT button. I need to read all the repeated forms and send it as JSONArray to the API.

My issue here is I am not able to keep the data consistent. For eg. If I put three forms and fill the data, then add more forms. Once I cross some amount of forms, the existing forms changes its original position, the new form take the second position from top and the remaining cells shuffles.

I want the cells to keep its original position throughout the process. Whatever the user does it should not change.

I would also like to read all the data when the SUBMIT button is pressed.

Please HELP!!

This is my JSON raw data

```
{
"participants":[

    {
        "name":"Ram",
        "mobile_no":"912368790",
        "events":[6,7,8,9,10],
        "gender":"male",
        "whatsapp_no":"912368790"
    },

    {
        "name":"Sham",
        "mobile_no":"9909123456",
        "events":[9,10],
        "gender":"male",
        "whatsapp_no":"9909123456"
    }

 ]
}
```

I am new in swift ,can any one help me how to handle data of tableview and JSON raw data in swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var addmore: UIButton!
var ar = ["Individual 1"]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return ar.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableTVC
    cell.indivuallbl.text! = ar[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 240.5
}
```

button actions

```
@IBAction func deleterow(_ sender: Any) {

    let point = (sender as AnyObject).convert(CGPoint.zero, to: tableview)
    guard let indexPath = tableview.indexPathForRow(at: point) else {
        return
    }
    ar.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    print(ar.count)

    tableview.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with:  .automatic)
    self.perform(#selector(reloadTable), with: nil, afterDelay: 0)


}

@objc func reloadTable() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableview.reloadData()
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableview.tableHeaderView = UIView.init(frame: .zero)

}

@IBAction func addmore(_ sender: Any) {


    ar.insert("Individual \(ar.count + 1 )", at: 0)
    print(ar.count)
    tableview.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0 , section: 0)], with: .automatic)

}

@IBAction func submitBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .data, object: nil)

    }





Uitableviewcell
```

class TableTVC: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var whatsappnotxt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var phonenotxt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var nametxt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var gendropDowntx: HADropDown!
@IBOutlet weak var indivuallbl: UILabel!



override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: 
#selector(datatable(notification:)), name: .data, object: nil

}




@objc func datatable(notification: Notification){




    let pP: [String: Any ] =
[

    "participants":[

        [

            nametxt.text = "\(nametxt!)",
            whatsappnotxt.text! = "\(whatsappnotxt!)",
            phonenotxt.text! = "\(phonenotxt!)"



              ]
    ]


    ]

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Authorization": "Bearer\(token)",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    ]


    Alamofire.request("http://api.domain.com/individual/add", method: .post, parameters: pP, encoding: JSONEncoding.default,headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response)

    }

}
```

}

extension Notification.Name{

```
static let data = Notification.Name("data")
```

}

How to show data correctly?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I have changed my question..

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the JSON data from Alamofire, you should decode it to an value type , such as struct.

define struct,

```
struct Participants: Decodable{
  var participants: [Participant]
 }

 struct Participant: Decodable{

  var name: String
  var mobile_no: String
  var events: [Int]
  var gender: String
  var whatsapp_no: String
 }
```

decode data

```
var trackList: TrackList = JSONDecoder().decode(TrackList.self. init(from: response))
```